# How to convert DocX from Xceed.Words.NET library to pdf and save it in a memory stream

Tags: c#, pdf, docx

I want to convert word byte array to pdf byte array.
I am using Xceed.Words.NET library

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(sourceFile.AttachedFile);
var doc = DocX.Load(stream);
var ms = new MemoryStream();

doc.SaveAs(ms);

var wByteArray = ms.GetBuffer();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(sourceFile.AttachedFile);

using (var document = DocX.Load(stream))
{
    stream = new MemoryStream();
    DocX.ConvertToPdf(document, stream);
}

var bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

As mentioned in the comment, you need a professional version of DocX library to convert a Word document to PDF.

If you're looking for free solution then perhaps you could try out [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document), its free version does support [converting to PDF](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-convert-word-pdf-html/304), but it has a document size limitation.
You can use it like this:

```
ComponentInfo.SetLicense("FREE-LIMITED-KEY");

var stream = new MemoryStream(sourceFile.AttachedFile);
var document = DocumentModel.Load(stream, LoadOptions.DocxDefault);

stream = new MemoryStream();
document.Save(stream, SaveOptions.PdfDefault);

var bytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Comment: DocX doesn't have ConvertToPdf method

Comment: @ArtushChibukhchyan only the professional version of DocX library, known as Xceed Words for .NET, supports converting to PDF. This is mentioned on their NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/